# Multistage Docker doesn't copy from previous stage

Tags: python, docker, docker-multi-stage-build

I have a problem with docker multistage. This is my first time making a multistage image and... it's not going well.

When I try to run a container, created with the image, I get the following error:

```bash
exec /app/app: no such file or directory
```

My image is built with the following dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10 AS builder

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pyinstaller

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

RUN pyinstaller --onefile --clean --name app --noconfirm app.py

FROM scratch

COPY --from=builder /app/dist/app /app/app

CMD ["/app/app"]
```

For some strange reason the file copies if I use python slim???

Comment: Do you have a reproducer you can share, e.g. a git repository?

Comment: Does `pyinstaller` produce a static binary?  Most binaries include a core set of shared-library dependencies, including the system dynamic loader and C library, but the `scratch` image doesn't include these.

Comment: @DavidMaze this wouldn't explain the `no such file or directtory`, would it?

Comment: It would; that's the error you get if you try to run an executable and its loader, interpreter, or C shared libraries are missing.

Comment: Huh. Today I learned.

Comment: you're correct that it doesn't have its dependencies, but I don't understand why it doesn't find the executable.

If I change to ubuntu image (just a random one) I get:
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.36' not found (required by /tmp/_MEIE1GhCQ/libstdc++.so.6)

Which is explainable because it's unsatisfied with its dependencies, but if I try it on scratch or alpine it just doesn't recognize the file.

If I sh into alpine and run ls - it appears, but if I run ./app - I get "./app: no such file or directory" and that's the behaviour I'm questioning